# Difference between Task Scheduler and Service

Tags: service, scheduled-tasks

I would like a program to run every night with no logged in user.

How should I implement- as a `service` or as a `scheduled task`?

Answer (score 1):

I have to assume this is for Windows (you may want to specify).  A Windows service is something that can be set to run all the time or run until complete.  Windows services can be set to automatically start or manually start.  Manual start is a bit of a misnomer as it can be programmatically started.  Manual really just means it does not start when the computer starts.  Another option for services is disabled.  Disabled is generally used to keep an annoying service (like the search indexer or iTunes helper) from wasting computer resources.

Services that run all the time will always take some amount of resources (CPU and memory).  If you used a Windows service your code could check the time and do what is needed at the appropriate time.  I don't think you will want this as it won't be worth the added overhead of the resource use.  Also, adding code to keep track of the time won't be worth your time.

I think you should use the task scheduler.  With the task scheduler the job will only be started at the scheduled time.  The job will run until it shuts itself off.  Windows will keep track of when it ran and if it returned an error (via stderr).  I've personally used the Windows task scheduler for some administrative tasks and found it to be very useful.

If you are using Linux, which I presume you are not, you will want to use a cron job.  There are tons of sites on how to do this including http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml .